# Monitor Gitea with Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, gitea

I have deployed [Gitea](https://gitea.io/). How can I want to monitor it with Prometheus ?

I have tried to scape the `/metrics` but I get no metrics (HTTP/404)

Answer (score 4):

Gitea can export Prometheus metrics (since ~ [1.7.1](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/pull/5256)) , but that's disabled by default.

In the configuration file `conf/app.ini`, you should add:

```
[metrics]
ENABLED=true
```

The metrics are exposed on the same port as gitea interface. The page is `/metrics`.

In your `prometheus.yml`configuration file, you should add the usual snippet:

```
  - job_name: 'gitea'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['vtlconout0001.retraite.lan:3030']
```

for more information and options, see [Gitea documentation](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/blob/master/docs/content/doc/advanced/config-cheat-sheet.en-us.md#metrics-metrics)